# Limit of a Riemann Sum as an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

The teacher assigned us Limits of Riemann sums to transform into their integral form only (we have not learned the FTC and thus cannot evaluate them using anti derivatives so we are just rewriting)

This one in particular was brought up and confused everyone:

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{n}}\right)\right)$

Some of us got:

\begin{equation}
\int _0^1\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)dx\:
\end{equation}

Others got:
\begin{equation}
\int _1^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\:
\end{equation}

When ran through my Ti-84 calculator, both integrals come out to be the exact same numerical answer. Who is correct? Or is there more than one answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct since $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln(1+x)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\ln 2$ and $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\ln x\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=2}=\ln 2$.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense now so they are both correct. But my question now is how does one derive 1/x+1 instead of 1/x. I got the latter expression with 1/x but have no idea how my classmates came up with 1/x+1

Comment: They choose the Riemann sum on the interval $[1,2]$ for function $1/x$, starting with initial point $1$, and then consider successively $1+1/n$, $1+2/n$,...

Comment: Another point of view is to choose $[0,1]$ for function $1/(x+1)$, starting with initial point $0$, and then consider successively $1/n$, $2/n$, when you plug to this function, it still gives you the same $1/1+1/(1+1/n)+\cdots$ as you may check easily.

Comment: Let's say we didn't know how to consider those points of views and just try to derive the upper and lower limits as well as the function from just the sum itself. Our teacher taught us to look at the last term to find the value of b because the last term in the summation gives us the final endpoint. In the case of this problem, we seem to have n-1, so we can't get a b value from here. How would we go about doing that?

Comment: You see, $(n-1)/n+1/n=1$, so either $1+1=2$ (in this case you treat $1/\color{red}x$ as a whole), or just $1$ (in this case you fix the $1$ in the function $1+/(\color{red}1+x)$). The idea, roughly speaking, if you know the width, in this case, which is $1/n$, try to do the last one with plus $1/n$ or minus $1/n$ (just in case you take the right endpoint for each).

Comment: Oh okay. Additionally, is this Riemann Sum considered a left Riemann Sum? if so why? me and a classmate think so but others seem to be in disagreement.

Comment: Not necessary left one, you may take right one, or even in the middle, just most of the limit questions that related to Riemann sum, they used to make it as the left one, I don't have idea why neither.

Answer (score 0):

In the first integral substitute $y=1+x$.

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing this substitution?

Comment: Then $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}$ will be reduced to $\int_1^2\frac{dy}{y}$, thus you can see the equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{1+x}$ is just $\frac{1}{x}$ shifted over $1$ space to the left, so this means in order for the integrals to be the same we need to add one to the bounds of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ to get the integral for $\frac{1}{x}$.